# How to find number sequence with multiple points in it like 1.2.3.4 from String?

Tags: java, regex

I want to find number sequence with multiple points in it like 1.2.3.4.5 from String containing it using RegX in Java. This type of number system is used in index system.

Ex. Hello world12.12.12world. From this String, I want to extract 12.12.12 only. I have tried below code, but it is not giving output if string is like **abc4.2.4.24abc**.

```
    Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(?:[\\dx]{1,6}\\.){0,6}[\\dx]{1,6}$");

    Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("4.2.4.2.4");
    while (m.find())
    {
        String s = m.group(0);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: Probably not the most efficient but [(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)](https://regex101.com/r/cFF2iq/2) will do it.

Comment: @AxelH For most purposes I think that a regular expression would do just fine. If multiple points means at least two, we will want `{2,}` instead of the last `+`. AFAIAC, you may make it into an answer.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that notation @OleV.V., thanks. I will not update it since I don't want to post it as an answer, this question isn't "complete" enough.

Comment: @hitesh.incept I’m afraid that such a comment may attract downvotes in itself. People like to judge for themselves what they find a good and a poor question and when to upvote and downvote (for myself I didn’t downvote the question, though the first version of it was worthy of a downvote; as it stands now, it’s much better, and I agree that it’s not worthy of any downvote any more).

Comment: As I have less experience in asking Question on Stackoverflow. i learned that there should be proper tried code snippet, so people can understand question easily. I am accepting that first version was not much worthy. Now, you can upvote my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice question hitesh, i got your idea. you can use regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` and `$` in the beginning and end of your pattern string requires the match to encompass the entire string. More precisely the `^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` the end. When your string is `"abc4.2.4.24abc"`, the sequence of digits and points neither begins at the start of the string nor ends at the end, so no match can be found.

Just delete `^` and `$` to find `4.2.4.24` inside `abc4.2.4.24abc`.